# sessions.setWindowValue() API for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon-webextensions

[Chrome's session api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions) does not implement `sessions.setWindowValue()` and `sessions.getWindowValue()` like in [Mozilla's API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sessions/setWindowValue).

Is there a similar api or workaround available for Chrome?

Comment: There's no workaround in the API. Use variables or chrome.storage API.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you explain a bit more? How can I attach a value to a window that will survive window close & restore?

Comment: Uhm, simply use a `Map` or object with window id as the key. Same for the storage option. In your background page, that is.

Comment: Will chrome restore the window with the same window ID? Firefox uses a new ID each time.

Comment: I don't know, but the order at least may be preserved.